# jQuery get entire html page including form input - send to php to save

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to use ajax to clone an entire html page with form data that is filled in the input from a users and then have php to save the entire page, included input values. I am able to clone but not send this data. How can I do this? I can send the html adding an .html() but I can't send the data with the html this way. If I just clone it, I get the data in the forms... but I can't send it. I am getting errors from jQuery in this image:

[image]

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
    {

 $('.ClickMe').click(function(event)
{
event.preventDefault();
var TheClone = $('.TheBody').clone();
console.log("Cloned");
//$('.TheBody').append(TheClone);

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "SaveForm.php",
data: {
    MyData: TheClone
},
success: function (data) {
    //
},
error: function (req, status, error) {}
});
```

Here is my php to save, which works but the data is not getting there from jQuery.

```
<?php
$Data = $_POST['MyData'];
file_put_contents('SavedForms/saved.php', $Data);

?>
```

Comment: `$Data = $_POST['MyData'];` don't you think

Comment: why would you not just seriealize the form and pass the input values?

Comment: If I serialized them then I do I get them back in the form again in the right places? I have never done that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the jQuery object as string (html) to the server you should first extract the HTML from that object:

```
var TheClone = $('.TheBody').clone().html();
```

Second (as already commented), inside `PHP` you should use `$_POST['MyData'];` (the key should be the string `MyData` and not a constant).

Comment: This works to save the html but not the form data in the input fields. How can I save this too?

Comment: I am able to clone but not send this data. How can I do this. I can send the html with your code but I can't send the data. If I just clone it, I get the data in the forms... but I can't send it.

Comment: How do you expect to get the data? Why not just send the form itself?

Comment: Then I have to put the data back in the form. Think of it this way. I need someone filling in a form all the fields, but later come back to it with all the info they left. That's not what I am doing but an example. I need the html and the form data they entered in one page.

Comment: What I am trying to do is create a form and have all that info in the form saved and sent. Later someone else will access that form and print it.

Comment: You don't need to save the html, you need to save only the values, and later on - to fill the values back to the form elements.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that possibility but there are MANY fields and I was trying to avoid writing code to fill in all those fields again. I figured saving Html and data would be easier and faster. If there was a way to send the clone via ajax, this would work I believe.

Comment: You don't need this. Just save all the values and later on populate then using a loop

Comment: sadly I am not sure how to do that. :(

Comment: Ask the right question and you will probably get the correct answer :-) I'll try to give you an example tomorrow. Gtg now

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**ISSUE RESOLVED:**

I got it to work by hard coding the users input into the html on a dom change then sending the html via ajax. I am sharing in hopes this idea may help others. I was able to clone the html page fine but I could not send this clone with the data via Ajax. I could save the html as Dekel mentioned above but this did not have the data.

So as a work around I saved the data to the html as the user changed it using jQuery. I used both inputs and checkboxes. I gave all checkboxes a class of MyCheck and all text inputs a class of MyInput. Here is the code I used.

```
$('.MyInput').on("change paste keyup", function() 
     {
    var MyVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr('value', MyVal);
    });

    $('.MyCheck').on("change paste keyup", function() 
     {
    if($(this).attr("checked"))
    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
    else
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');

    });


     $('.ClickMe').click(function(event)
    {
    event.preventDefault();

    var TheClone = $(".TheBody").html();

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "SaveEnrollment.php",
    data: {
       MyData: TheClone
    },
    success: function (data) {
       window.location = "/thank-you";
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {}
});
```